# How to increase /specific filesystem directory size manually in Red Hat 5.6

Tags: rhel, mount

I want to increase the size of a specific filesystem in RHEL 5.6, like `uw04` as you can see here

```
/dev/mapper/xxxxx-uw04--vol size=109G  used=102G  Avail=873M
```

I don't know which filesystem used..

Is there anyway to increase the size of 102G? Because only available have 873M and I afraid it will be cause the problem.

Version: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)

Comment: It seems you are talking about filesystems, not about folders.

Comment: Yes that's correct, but anyway I want to increase the size and why give me avail only 873M and I have 109G and used 102G?

Comment: Then why don't you edit the question? The difference between size, used and avail is because some space is needed for inodes and other filesystem data.

Comment: @Ameer. Are you using lvm by any chance? Could you please(if using)  post on your question the result of the comands `vgs` and `lvs` as root?

Comment: No, I don't use lvm. only I connect by cygwin and use df -h command

Comment: AFAIK Cygwin doesn't use a Device Mapper, so please be more specific with your set-up. For example, is this really Cygwin, or is it some different machine entirely?

Comment: Only I have Cygwin and when I used this command df -h, it shows me this result:/dev/mapper/xxxxxxxxxxx-uw04--vol
                      109G  102G  873M 100% /uw04

Comment: My question is: any way to increase the size for uw04...

Comment: _@Ameer_, would you please click [edit] and advise what type of filesystem was used to make _uw04_? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use below command 

lvresize -L +Mention_extra_sizewhich_you_want_to_add /dev/vgname/lvname
resize2fs /dev/vgname/lvname
```